# SharePoint 2010 - REST - retrieve group members

Tags: rest, spservices, jsom

I am building a form using REST and am trying to create a drop down based on a person/group field.

`'..ListData.svc/listNameFieldName'` does not seem to work for those field types and accessing `'..ListData.svc/UserInformationList'` does not identify group members.

Is there a way for me to access this information via REST? If not, would using **JSOM/SPServices** provide a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can get below REST method to get users from the group.

**GET request example**: `Get the users in a group`

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /sitegroups(7)/users
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: Will this solution work for SharePoint 2010? I believe that AppContextSite is only for 2013.

Comment: Yes it will work